# What are the steps for deploying a Dataflow app

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am a newbie to Dataflow/GCP.  I have created a working Dataflow app and have tested it running from Eclipse.
I have been reading the DataFow docs provided on GCP site searching for the steps to take for deployment of a Dataflow app to GCP, but can't find any detail information on that.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Have you read this quick start? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse#configure-execution-options provides details on how to deploy an application to the Cloud.  You'll specify a project and Cloud Storage bucket, and then be able to monitor the progress of your job.